# Console C# call nested function

Tags: c#, loops, console

Hey guys can you tell me how should can I call "print: if . It never goes inside print if . It loops out.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
        if (commands == "Read" || commands == "read")
        {

            fileread obj = new fileread();

            lcsString = obj.getlcs();

            commands = Console.ReadLine(); // If command = print I want it go to print              but it never goes . it loops out
        }
        else if (commands =="print")
        {


        }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any loop here. And it is not clear what you asking..

Comment: I meant it completes the execution .I want the program to again run .

Comment: Best way to compare string without sensitive case: if(commands.ToLower() == "read") . But you should edit your post and explain better your question, it's confusing.

Comment: the value of "commands" is updated so how can I call print if . Thats my question. Since am already if the one if it cant proceed to another as condition is matched .

Comment: once your code enters the if block, it cant go to the else block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear what you asking but looks like there is an option;

Moving your `commands = Console.ReadLine()`  outside in your if statement. Like;

```
commands = Console.ReadLine();
if (commands == "Read" || commands == "read")
{
    fileread obj = new fileread();
    lcsString = obj.getlcs();   
}
else if (commands =="print")
{
}
```

Because if your first `if` statement works, that's mean your `command` is `Read` or `read`. After that, your program doesn't go your `else if` part. It goes outside of your if statement.

Answer (score 3):

You can use while, here you go..

```
while (!commands.Equals("exit", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
    if (commands.Equals("read", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        fileread obj = new fileread();
        lcsString = obj.getlcs();
    }
    else if (commands == "print")
    {
        // print ...
    }
    commands = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Thanku . I just thought about it ! Sorry :( for giving u guys some trouble.